# Building Failure with PCL

Tags: c#, appveyor

My project is hosted on [github](https://github.com/pwasiewicz/MicroPerformanceComparer). Everything gets compiled fine on my local machine, but AppVeyor reports some weird errors like:

> Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'AssemblyTitle' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

It looks like some base references are not recognized. Is PCL supported on AppVeyor? I could not find any info.
What can I do to fix errors?

Comment: Looks like you've already managed to build it successfully: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pwasiewicz/microperformancecomparer

Comment: Yes, I've ended up wtih writing own PS script :)